# dj-rest-auth/registration return http 204 no content

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, dj-rest-auth

I were following the book Django for APIs by William.S.Vincent. In Chapter 8: User Authentication, I make Implementing token authentication and use dj-rest-auth and django-allauth to make registration. In the book after register the http return 201 created, it created new account and return API auth key token, save that in db.
[image]

With my it return http 204 no content( not return API auth key token ), it still created a new account but don't create key token for account.

My url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('api/v1/', include("posts.urls")), # v1 for api version 1. (Name for each api route)
path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),  # build-in log in/out rest
path("api/v1/dj-rest-auth/", include("dj_rest_auth.urls")), #url for dj_rest_auth
path("api/v1/dj-rest-auth/registration/", include("dj_rest_auth.registration.urls")),
```

]

My settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django.contrib.sites',

#3party
"rest_framework",
"corsheaders",
"rest_framework.authtoken",
"allauth", 
"allauth.account",  
"allauth.socialaccount", 
"dj_rest_auth",
"dj_rest_auth.registration", 

#local
'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',
'posts.apps.PostsConfig',]

REST_FRAMEWORK = { # new
"DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": [
    "rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated",
],
"DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": [
    "rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication",
    "rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication",
],}
```

I compared with github files both author and found no difference.
github:https://github.com/wsvincent/restapiswithdjango/tree/master/ch8-blog-user-auth

Has there been any change to the version? Thank for you time.

Comment: What version of Django are you running? I noticed this when I updated Django, Django rest and allauth to latest versions. When I was running Django 3.2 everything was working according to the book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having the same issue, I looked directly at `dj_rest_auth`source code and saw the following:

**File:** `apps/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dj_rest_auth/registration/views.py`

```
if api_settings.USE_JWT:
    data = {
        'user': user,
        'access_token': self.access_token,
        'refresh_token': self.refresh_token,
    }
    return api_settings.JWT_SERIALIZER(data, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data
elif api_settings.SESSION_LOGIN:
    return None
else:
    return api_settings.TOKEN_SERIALIZER(user.auth_token, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data
```

Adding `SESSION_LOGIN: false` in my settings.py solved the issue, and I created a unittest to make sure it doesn't appear again.

**File:** `settings.py`

```
REST_AUTH = {
    'SESSION_LOGIN': False
}
```

See [dj-rest-auth documentation](https://dj-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html) for more details.

**File:** `users.test.py`

```
class ApiUsersTest(TransactionTestCase):
    """ Account retrieve """

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = APIClient()

    def test_registration_new_user(self):
        """
            Create a user using rest-auth and get auth key in response.
        """
        response = self.client.post('/api/v1/rest-auth/registration/', {
            'username': 'test',
            'password1': 'testtest',
            'password2': 'testtest',
            'email': 'test@email.com',
        }, format='json')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        data = response.json()
        # Test if response data key is define, a string, and not empty or blank
        self.assertTrue('key' in data)
```

Comment: Wow, nice that solved that for me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: why should I set `SESSION_LOGIN = False` and disable session authentication? In login, you won't get cookies to the client. I also face the same issue, but I don't think this is the solution we need.

Comment: Agreed with @MarufKhan, this isn't a solution

Answer (score 0):

make the `SESSION_LOGIN = FALSE` in dj-rest-auth is not correct way to solve this problem. in this way you just destroy the Session authentication method which is not good! I think this problem because of Django and DRF updates. it's better use JWT package which is more good than this.